# Install older version of rvm on OS X Lion 10.7.2?

Tags: xcode, rvm, osx-lion, homebrew

I have on old xserve that's stuck on 10.7.2 Lion. It cannot be upgraded higher (e.g. 10.7.6) because any higher than 10.7.2 causes a system crash due to the RAID card on the machine.

This means I'm stuck with XCode 4.2.1. The cli tools for xcode 451 installed fine though.

I've managed to get homebrew installed and working.

When installing rvm I'm getting the error:
"Xcode version older than 4.6.2 installed...."

(xcode 4.2.1 is the highest allowed version for 10.7.2)

Did rvm work in the past on 10.7.2? If so, can I just install an old version of rvm that uses xcode 4.2.1?

Comment: I was able to install the rvm dev branch. However, when I try to use it I get the same error (too old xcode version)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get things working with rvm 1.16.15.